# Linking subprocesses with tee in python

Tags: python, subprocess, tee

I'm playing with `tee` and Python's subprocesses, and have some issues. I would like to write a Python program that could take a command (that writes to stdout), and feed the output to a given number of commands. I have realized it may possible to use `fifo`s for this.

I have also found various solutions involving Python; I am trying to restrict myself to low-level OS operations, for performance reasons (the idea would be to write a backup tool, so the data streams may be huge); although I might be misleading, and using pure python operation might the way to go ([here's](https://kevinmccarthy.org/2016/07/25/streaming-subprocess-stdin-and-stdout-with-asyncio-in-python/) an example of how it could be done in Python).

Here's a small version of what I wrote so far

```py
import os
import subprocess

def test_pipe_fanout_example():
    fifo_input = "/tmp/fifo_i"
    fifo_output = "/tmp/fifo_o"
    for filename in [fifo_input, fifo_output]:
        os.mkfifo(filename)

    input_cmd = "echo -n 'hello world'"
    out_file = "/tmp/out"

    stdin = os.open(fifo_output, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
    op = subprocess.Popen(f"cat > {out_file}", stdin=stdin, shell=True, close_fds=True)

    fanout_command = f"tee {fifo_output}"
    fanout_stdin = os.open(fifo_input, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
    stdout = os.open(fifo_input, os.O_WRONLY)

    print("Running input")
    ip = subprocess.Popen(input_cmd, stdout=stdout, shell=True, close_fds=True)

    print("Running fanout")
    fanout = subprocess.Popen(
        fanout_command,
        stdin=fanout_stdin,
        shell=True, close_fds=True
    )
    ip.wait()
    print("IP", ip.returncode)
    os.close(stdout)
    fanout.wait()
    os.close(fanout_stdin)
    print(f"fanout {fanout}")

    op.wait()
    print(f"OP {op}")


    for filename in [fifo_input, fifo_output]:
        os.unlink(filename)

    with open(out_file) as f:
        data = f.read()
        assert data == "hello world"
```

The program runs, but the `/tmp/out` file is empty at the end of the operation. Does anyone have any clues of what I might be doing wrong, or if using Python's primitives might be a better idea?

---

Edit: I feel like the problem might come from the fact that `tee` reads stdin in a blocking manner. This makes running the `tee` subprocess before the input process fail with `/usr/bin/tee: read error: Resource temporarily unavailable`; running it after the input subprocess will lead to some of the streamed data be lost.

Comment: Using `shell=True` with the `fanout_command` is a bug; you are effectively running `tee` without arguments. This is a common FAQ.

Comment: Also, note that `cat > {out_file}` and `shell=True` is a bad idea if in real-world environments external users can control your filenames. If someone says they want a file named `$(rm -rf ~)`, you don't want that command being run.

Comment: Using hardcoded filenames in `/tmp` is _also_ a bad idea for security reasons -- they lend themselves to symlink attacks. There's a reason Python includes a `tempfile` module.

Comment: Also, don't think of tee as "low-level". Really, it's not. Low-level OS resources are things like the `read()` and `write()` syscalls, and `mkfifo()`. Python has direct access to all the OS-level facilities `tee` is using -- unless you're on a system with _very_ limited CPU resources where the time between syscalls matters, you're not going to be buying anything useful by using `tee` here. (And if you're that low on CPU cycles, then you _really_ shouldn't want to pay the costs associated with `shell=True`, or with `fork()`ing off unnecessary subprocesses, or even with using Python at all).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Yeah all these hardcoded values are here to provide a short script, as they are not very relevant to the stated problem.

Also `shell=True` was used mostly here to be able to use `cat` , and I got thing a bit mixed up and eded up using it everywhere.

Comment: You don't need `shell=True` to use `cat` -- it's an external executable, not a shell builtin. Anyhow, much more efficient to write direct to a file, rather than to write to the stdin of a copy of `cat` that in turn writes to the file.

Comment: ...insofar as you mean `shell=True` to use `cat >somefile`, one could switch to `subprocess.Popen(['cat'], stdout=open('somefile', 'w'))`. Still silly and useless to use cat at all, but you get the same redirection without the overhead of a shell.

Comment: Indeed, thanks for the tip. Although the `cat` here is mostly for testing purposes. The end goal is not to write to files, but rather feed the stream to `rclone` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments in the OP, and after fidling some more, I think I can present a solution to this problem. The tee operation is indeed not too complicated to implement in Python !

```py
import os
import subprocess


def fd_fanout(fd_in, fd_out):
    file_in = os.fdopen(fd_in, "rb")
    os.set_blocking(file_in.fileno(), False)
    file_out = os.fdopen(fd_out, "wb")
    while True:
        data = file_in.read(1000)
        if data is None:
            break
        file_out.write(data)


def test_pipe_fanout_example():
    data_in = "hello world"*1000
    fifo_input = "/tmp/fifo_i"
    fifo_output = "/tmp/fifo_o"
    for filename in [fifo_input, fifo_output]:
        os.mkfifo(filename)

    input_cmd = ["/usr/bin/echo", "-n", data_in]
    out_file = "/tmp/out"

    output_r = os.open(fifo_output, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
    output_w = os.open(fifo_output, os.O_WRONLY)
    input_r = os.open(fifo_input, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
    input_w = os.open(fifo_input, os.O_WRONLY)

    out = open(out_file, "wb")

    print("running input")
    ip = subprocess.Popen(input_cmd, stdout=input_w, close_fds=True)

    print("Running output")
    op = subprocess.Popen("cat", stdin=output_r, stdout=out, close_fds=True)

    fd_fanout(input_r, output_w)

    ip.wait()
    print("IP", ip)
    os.close(input_w)
    # os.close(input_r)

    op.wait()
    print("OP", op)
    os.close(output_r)

    for filename in [fifo_input, fifo_output]:
        os.unlink(filename)

    with open(out_file) as f:
        data = f.read()
        print("DATA", len(data))
        assert data == data_in
```